# JqueryMobile 1.4.3. icons not appearing?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i'm developing a mobile application for Android on Dreamweaver and using jquerymobile 1.4.3. The problem is that none of the icons appears, only the circle round them. The images folder is on the same folder that the css and js files, as proposed in other questions, but this has not solved my problem. Can anyone help me?

My code is:

```
<link href="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Edit**: when i test the application on Android device, the icons appear but not on Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to load the icons.min.css, unless you have a customized theme. My best shot is the order the files are loaded.

Load the files the standard way: (http://jquerymobile.com/download/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

or with a customized theme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mytheme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.4.min.css" /> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've loaded the files like you say but the problem persists. Even if I open the file index.html of jquery.mobile-1.4.3.zip button demo I am not able to see the icons on the buttons on dreamweaver's live tab, I only see the grey circle round them. Any other idea? Thanks

Comment: I suspect this is a Dreamweaver issue, but have a look at these:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/listview-icons-not-showing-any-solution-to-this-ongoing-bug
http://www.webteacher.ws/2012/02/21/using-jquery-mobile-in-dreamweaver-cs-5-5/